# Unable to upload Shiny application to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making use of one deprecated package in CRAN called "sentiment" which is dependent of another deprecated package called "Rstem" in my Shiny application. Because of that, I couldn't host my shiny application (that is working properly locally in my machine) to shinyapps.io

```
Error: Unable to retrieve package records for the following packages:
- "Rstem"
```

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! I just integrated the code files present inside the packages and used directly in my application. This eliminated the use of packages that are deprecated.